# What is the role of 和 in “很高兴和您见面”

Tags: grammar

I am fairly new in learning Mandarin, and I am having a bit of trouble understanding the role of 和 in "很高兴和您见面" . From my understanding, 和 means "and" or "together with";

Directly translating this sentence:

> 很高兴 (happy)
>
> 和 (and/with)
>
> 您 (you) 见面 (meet).

Is it to connect 高兴 and 您 ？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

和 can also mean 'with'

[1.很高兴][2.**和**您][3.见面]

[1. very glad][3.to meet] [2.**with** you]

You can also use 跟 or 與 for 'with'

Comment: Oh I see. In this case, is it correct if 和 was omitted ? Just 很高兴您见面 ？

Comment: @AvadaKedavra You need "和" in "很高兴和您见面". (very glad to meet with you) ; You can rephrase the sentence to "很高兴见到您" (very glad to see you); 很高兴您见面 would mean "very glad you meet" which make no sense